# Deprecated: KeyStoreKeyFactory is Deprecated

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

Since security.oauth2 is deprecated, what can be used to generate a KeyPair from .jks file instead of KeyStoreKeyFactory?

Answer (score 1):

I believe You can use the other dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-rsa</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.11.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```